# Python loop through list of IDs and grab data from JSON file based on these

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am very new to python so i apologise in advance. I want to grab the image url from the JSON file.

[The hierarchy of the JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77j8Y.png)

For example, i can get the the above product ID(16796655) image url by doing:

```
data = json.loads(script)
img_name = (data['entities']['products']['16796655']['images'])
print(img_name)
```

and this grabs it just fine.

However I have a list of IDs and would like to just make one request to get each image url that falls under these IDs: 16796655, 17329706, 17741328, 17732192

Do i need to put all my IDs into an array and then do a **for** and somehow reference the ID array in this section of the data call?  ['16796655'] as the data call obviously requires the ID to be referenced inside it in order to know which image url to get.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
ids = ["16796655", "17329706", "17741328", "17732192", ...]

for i in ids:
  if i in data['entities']['products']:
     img_name = (data['entities']['products'][i]['images'])
     print(img_name)
```

This should work.

Comment: @Jab should be good now

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to put all my IDs into an array and then do a for and somehow reference the ID array in this section of the data call?

Yes that's exactly what you could do.

```
data = json.loads(script)
products = data["entities"]["products"]
ids = ["16796655", "17329706", "17741328", "17732192"]
```

to get them all in a list

```
all_images = [products[i]["images"] for i in ids if i in products]
```

although I suggest putting them into a dict so you can assign the id to their respective images

```
all_images = {i: products[i]["images"] for i in ids if i in products}
```

or if you only need to print them

```
for i in ids:
    if i in products:
        print(products[i]['images'])
```

Bonus, using `operator.itemgetter` *(assuming all ids exist in products or you get an error)*:

```
get_ids = operator.itemgetter(*ids)
get_image = operator.itemgetter("images")

all_images = dict(zip(ids, map(get_image, get_ids(products))))
#result is the same as my dict approach
```